# URL Re-writing rule in htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

My current URL is coming like below.

http://testnewbisptrainings.bispsolutions.com/course-main.php?sid=5

And I want URL in below format

http://testnewbisptrainings.bispsolutions.com/ETL

Solution using IBM DataStage

So, currently after the domain name course page and course ID is coming whereas I want course name only after the domain name.

Also, we have changed our domain HTTP to HTTPS.
Please let me know how to write rule so that it will go on https only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect all of your requests to the index.php and always get a $url?

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(config|core|static|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If you want to redirect always to HTTPS you can change the config in the 000-default.conf

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
        . . .

        Redirect permanent "/" "https://your_domain_or_IP/"

        . . .
</VirtualHost>
```